# Finding coordinates of pyramid with known base, and known angles for apex

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a regular pyramid, where I know the 3d coordinates of all points on the base, and I know all of the angles associated with the apex.   I'm wondering if there's a known method to determine the coordinates of the apex given this information (I figure there should be six unique solutions, but I've not derived a decent method to determine the exact coordinates).

Comment: Questions like this are off-topic here -- you might ask them at Math.SE.

Comment: Could you describe what are "all of the angles associated with the apex"? Angles of the faces incident to the apex? Dihedral angles along the edges?

Answer (score 1):

This might help: An illustration of how I computed the coordinates for a tetrahedron from the base and the shape of the lateral faces:

---

[image: Fig.25.27]

---

Figure from *[Geometric Folding Algorithms: 
Linkages, Origami, Polyhedra](http://www.gfalop.org/)*, p.406.